# Thermionic emission

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, physics, materials, x-rays

I am doing the calculation for the "finding the temperature of filament".

I tried with:

- Resistance (R=V/I)
- Resistivity (ρ = R·L/A)
- Temperature (T = (ρ-ρ<sub>0</sub>/ρ<sub>0</sub>-δ) + T<sub>0</sub>)

Here ρ<sub>0</sub>, δ and T<sub>0</sub> are for reference resistivity, temperature coefficient, and temperature respectively; this all-constant value is for room temperature (20°C).

But I can't get any good data. Please share your experience or knowledge.

Comment: Finding a filament temperature is difficult. (At least in the case where there is also field emission possible -- Wehnelt lens.) People spend a great deal of money on the problem. They do so because it impacts the cost of operating IC lithography systems, if nothing else. And they still fail. What makes you think this is an easy problem?

Comment: You don't use the thermoionic coefficients of "heat" "emission" or transmission?

Comment: These are thermodynamic heat exchange problem.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Can you share your calculations? Usually calc. through  temperature coefficient of resistance gives good result.

Comment: Dear all I am currently finding the temp of filament when I apply 2 V and 10 Amp at filament then could you tell me what the temp at filament is? but the R= V/I is not working for the same conduction, Whan I increasing the current also increasing temp how?

Comment: Something to read (sorry, in french, "Google translate" is your friend) https://on5vl.org/fichiers/tension-filament.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching something as this?

From this [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00205420/document) ...

[image]

EE&O ... Here is a Maple sheet for evaluation.  Hope this help.
NB: kappa and S (area of the emissive device) are "evaluated" coefficients.
In this sheet, S is the area of a cylindrical wire \$S = pi * D * L\$, d=100 microns, L=10 mm.

[image]

[image]